# Replacing a pdf file -- it works with sed, but when using Java, the images inside the pdf file disappear. Why?

Tags: java, pdf, groovy, replace

I have a pdf that I downloaded from this link:

https://invoicetemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/freelance-writer-invoice-template.pdf

and I use pdf tk for uncompress the pdf

pdftk file.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress

When I try to replace using `sed` it works.

However when I use `Java`, the images of logo and text inside pdf disppear.

I don't know why -- please help me.

This is my code in shell:

```
sed -e "s/ORIGINALSTRING/NEWSTRING/g" <uncompressed.pdf >modified.pdf
```

and this is my code using Groovy:

```
(new File('uncox3.pdf')).write(    new File('uncompressed.pdf').getText().replaceAll(/ORIGINALSTRING/,"NEWSTRING"))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I will not download a PDF and run a shell command on it. What is the expected behaviour, what happens instead, why do you expect just changing a string inside the pdf will even work in the first place?

Comment: please wait I will post the results in this moment

Comment: you're just doing a string replace on the filename not the contents in the Groovy example

Comment: How I could correct this?

Comment: I post the images of my result with sed and with groovy I dont know because this happens ; I think that maybe can be the encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution get  from my another question

very thankyou all for help

```
   def s = new File("uncompressed.pdf").getText("ISO-8859-1").replaceAll("ORIGINALSTRING", "NEWSTRING")

    def bb = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")

    new File("uncox3.pdf").setBytes(bb)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `sed` command also does damage the pdf if the original string and the replacement string differ in size. In that case the replacement changes the actual starting offsets of indirect pdf objects without updating them in the cross reference section of the file.

PDF readers  often attempt to repair the cross references as soon as they discover problems without a warning which might be why you didn't notice.

Nonetheless, people retrieving your invoice files may reject them as unparsable, you cannot expect them to accept broken files.

This being said, the reason why your groovy code more visibly damages the pdf likely is that explicit binary-to-text conversion using `getText` and the implicit text-to-binary conversion in `write`.

If in the assumed encoding there isn't a character (sequence) for each possible byte sequence, the binary-to-text conversion uses a replacement character instead when hitting such a byte sequence, and the final text-to-binary conversion does not know the original byte sequence for those replacement characters.

Utf-8 meanwhile is a common default encoding assumed here, and for utf-8 there indeed are many byte sequences without meaning.

Explicitly using an encoding like Latin-1 instead might make your java code run similar to your sed command.

But as mentioned above, even that would damage the pdf and shouldn't be used for anything but experimenting, not for sending the result PDFs to others, in particular not for serious stuff like invoices or contracts.

Comment: very thankyou for help ; i post the solution to this problem